# Spring) why is STOMP header vanishing going from ChannelInterceptor to MessageHandler?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

now I'm implementing a simple chat service using Spring for backend and react for frontend.

I want to add userName on the messages, but the client is only giving me the content of the message and jwt token containing claims of their Id and userName

so I went on and implemented a ChannelInterceptor that intercepts all messages comming through to parse jwt token in its presend method, and then set the sender's information on the header.

my guess was that since I set the header before message gets to @MessageMapping, I will have the message with userInformation in its header where the message is actually processed and sent to its channel subscribers.

but as it turns out, the message that comes through actually does not contain the headers that I set.

anyone have idea why the header is vanishing? Ive checked that in preSend method, the header is properly set in the STOMP custom header.

this is my implementation of ChannelInterceptor

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class StompHandler implements ChannelInterceptor {
    private final JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand()) ||
                StompCommand.DISCONNECT.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand()) ||
                    StompCommand.UNSUBSCRIBE.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())
        ) {
            return message;
        }

        System.out.println("headerAccessor = " + headerAccessor);
        String bearerToken = String.valueOf(headerAccessor.getNativeHeader("ACCESS_TOKEN")).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");

        if (bearerToken.equals("null")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("asdasd");
        }
        String token = jwtUtil.removePrefix(bearerToken);

        if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("asdf");
        }

        Claims claims = jwtUtil.getClaimsFromToken(token);

        ChatUserPrincipal userPrincipal;
        try{
            userPrincipal = new ChatUserPrincipal(
                    Long.valueOf(claims.get("userId").toString()),
                    claims.get("nickName").toString(),
                    claims.get("profileUrl").toString()
            );
        } catch(RuntimeException e){
            log.info("asd");
            throw new NullPointerException("asd : asdfasdf");
        }
        headerAccessor.setHeader("asdfasdf", userPrincipal);


        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.getPayload(),message.getHeaders());
    }
}
```